# How can i count array keys in ezpublish?

Tags: php, ezpublish

i have a problem counting array keys value in ezpublish whose php function is

```
array_count_values();
```

i need a similar function in ezpublish. Is there any operators in ezpublish or i have to make an extension for it too?

Comment: it's an cms system in PHP. moreover it works with enterprises level

Comment: for more detail follow the link http://ez.no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After research for long time i found that, there is no any ez publish template operators for `array_count_values();` we have to make an extension for it. And process of making extension is given in the link below.

http://blog.developeronhire.com/using-custom-php-functions-in-ez-publish-templates/

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

The count operator is what you are looking for here, it appears :

```
{def $arrayCount = $myArray|count()}
```

More on this operator in the documentation : http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Template-operators/Variable-and-type-handling/count

Generally, feel free to also drop your questions on the eZ Publish Community Portal : http://share.ez.no (but i think you already know this place ;) )

Hope it helps,
Cheers,

Comment: {def $count = $myArray|count()} just count number of arrays items. eZ publish teplating engine just don't have a function which works as array_count_values(); in PHP. so we have to make an extension for it. If there is any please let me know. Anyway thanks Nicolas for your time

Comment: @Sujeet : Ok, got you. Sorry for reading through the initial post too quickly. You may want to have a look at this : http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Configuration-files/template.ini/PHP/PHPOperatorList] `PHPOperatorList` configuration directive in template.ini, allowing you to plug-in any simple php function directly into eZ Publish's template language. Cheers Sujeet !

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the php function as a [new template operator](http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Configuration-files/template.ini/PHP/PHPOperatorList) for templates to use.

Add it to the template.ini override file.

Answer (score 1):

As said by Nicolas, you can map any PHP functions to a template operator if :

- the function returns the result by value and not by reference
- the function takes only one parameters (this might work with functions
  having one mandatory parameter and others which are optional but I
  can remember that it generates PHP warnings and that the optionals parameters
  will be ignored)

Documentation : http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Configuration-files/template.ini/PHP/PHPOperatorList

So doing what you want is really easy since [array_key_values()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-count-values.php) is a good candidate and matches the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function count_array_key($arr)
{          
    return count(array_keys($arr));
}
```

usage

```
$array = array("color" => array("blue", "red", "green"),
               "size"  => array("small", "medium", "large"));
echo count_array_key($array);
```

Comment: i can't use php functions over here just ezpublish templating operators can be used. just can use if, foreach, for, count

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use PHP native functions, you really should use this extension : http://projects.ez.no/wrap_operator

You just have to enable the selected function in the ini file of the extension and to use it in your templates.

For example :

```
{def $html = wrap_php_func('str_replace', array('&amp;', '&', $article.data_map.descriptif.data_text))}
```

It will save your life !

Answer (score 0):

If adding it to the template.ini of your site's extension does not work, just create an autoload. They are very simple to create and is how I often add any php function I need. You don't need a new extension for the autoload, just add it to your existing extension in the *autoloads* directory. *Don't forget to declare your autoload in the eztemplateautoload.php file, you will likely have to add one of those to your autoloads directory too.*